# Camel route return type variation

Tags: json, jackson, apache-camel

I have a Camel route that will either return a custom MyPojo.class or a custom RouteRequestException.class. Here's the route:

```
.from("direct:myPojoTest")

// retrieve MyPojo
.to(myPojoQueue)

.choice()
   .when(header(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT))
      .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, RouteRequestException.class)
   .endChoice()
   .otherwise()
      .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, MyPojo.class)
.end()

//.to("log:mypojo?level=DEBUG&showAll=true&multiline=true")
```

What comes back from the myPojoQueue is a JSON string representing either a MyPojo instance or a RouteRequestException. In the event an exception is sent back, the Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT header is being set on the message.

The problem is if my route ends with the last .end() (tied to the .choice()) what ends up returning to caller is the JSON string returned from myPojoQueue, basically rendering the unmarshal() statements useless. However, if I uncomment the .to("log...") statement the desired unmarshal() takes affect (in either case).

Every unmarshal() example I've seen shows a .to() immediately following. Based on that (and the problem I'm seeing) I'm guessing that the unmarshal() doesn't actually execute until another endpoint is invoked. Does anyone know if that's true? Do I need to add a "no-op" to() just to make this work (hacky)?

Should I be trying to unmarshal to a POJO's in a different way in this case?

I should also mention that I'm using Camel 2.15.2.